# Nvidia driver issues after installing 19.04 on Asus UX433F

Tags: drivers, 19.04, software-sources

I am using an Asus UX433F. Had some issues with screen going black after wake up from suspend mode and was advised to upgrade to 19.04. I have done fresh installation but running into some other problems now.

1. I have to use the `nomodeset` option to be able to boot successfully into Ubuntu, doesn't work the first time, after numerous tries I got it working.
2. I am not able to update so I can have the latest Nvidia drivers to solve the issue mention in point 1.

**Update: Found the issue on this one, removed systemback and all good.**
I noticed the following error message when trying to update, which tells me the update source is not correct, how can I fix this:

```
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu disco Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I have been following [this itsfoss article](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/) to try and solve issues mentioned above.

Comment: You have to remove this ppa from your system. Run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:nemh/systemback`, then you will be able to update.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @karel & my update in the description the problem was systemback, I have removed it and it is working.

I will be creating separate thread with the Nvidia graphics issue.